# Detailed and thorough books about the history of mathematics

Tags: reference-request, math-history, book-recommendation

Regards.. i would like to ask about some high quality books about the history of mathematics. The ideal books should provide detailed and thorough history of mathematics, with good **images** and **manuscripts**.

Books available at libraries are preferred, information about the library would be useful. I appreciate some thoughts on this, thanks..

Comment: See [History of Mathematics](https://www.google.it/search?q=history+of+mathematics&safe=active&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj47MuQg5LTAhVCaRQKHSy9CDAQ_AUICigD&biw=1517&bih=708).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dirk Struick's *Source Book in Mathematics, 1200 - 1800* has the manuscripts you desire. His *Concise History of Mathematics* is also excellent. A readable and historiographically critical recent book is Luke Hodgkin's *A History of Mathematics: from Mesopotamia to Modernity*, which can be found in .pdf form. Then there are Carl Boyer's works, all canonical. His book on calculus is especially good, if this is your area of interest.

Comment: Regards @AmpleMimic , thanks for the info. Sorry for the late response. Carl Boyer may seem to fit, because his profile as historian in mathematics. May i ask what do you mean by canonical?

Answer (score 1):

You can try checking out the references listed in the [Wikipedia page on "History of Mathematics"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_mathematics).

I would think most of these references / books are available at a library nearest you.  If in doubt, you can just access your local library's Online Public Access Catalog (OPAC) and take it from there.

Happy reading!

Answer (score 1):

Carl B. Boyer, $\textit{A history of Mathematics}$. I'm reading it and it's very detailed (and long!).